# Code highlighting for VBA

Tags: feature-request

The office apps use a subset of Visual Basic for many coding routines, and there are many tags that reference VBA, (vba / access-vba etc).

Could we have code highlighting for this language please.

Comment: The [tag:vba] tag *does* have syntax highlighting. Is there a place where it's not being applied?

Comment: interesting - access-vba doesn't

Comment: @animuson many`Ms Access` questions have only [access-vba] not {vba], and this tag is clearly a code tag, so please add the code language.